# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed when using Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring

I am querying a table which has almost 400 million records and I need to process the data based on the timestamp that would return around 1000 to 1500 records and it takes almost 5 minutes to execute.
Initially it was running fine without any errors and when records for that table started increasing, started facing an exception

```
> org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from tbl_user_history where app_key=? and rec_id= ? and caller_id=? and call_time > ? and call_time < ?;]; Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

After seeing this error, tried to work with a traditional way of connecting to the database(using connection statement and ResultSet) and fetching records, but no luck, but still the same error.

This is the program

```
public class UserHistory {
private static JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObjectUser = null;
private static UrlDetails urlDetails;
static {
    loadConfigs();
}
public static void loadConfigs() {
    ApplicationContext usersContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("user_db.xml");
    DataSource usersDataSource = (DataSource) usersContext.getBean("dataSourceUsers");
    jdbcTemplateObjectUser = new JdbcTemplate(usersDataSource);

    ApplicationContext contextUrl = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application.xml");
    urlDetails = (UrlDetails) contextUrl.getBean("urlDetails");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            SqlRowSet usersRst = jdbcTemplateObjectUser.queryForRowSet(
                    "select * from tbl_user_history where app_key=? and rec_id= ? and caller_id=? and call_time > ? and call_time < ?;",
                    new Object[] { urlDetails.AppKey(), urlDetails.getCallerId(), 1,covertedToThreeHoursBefore,covertedThreeHoursAfter});

            Set<String> usersIds = new HashSet<>();
            while (usersRst.next()) {
                usersIds.add(usersRst.getString("user_id"));

            }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem while trying to store into database"+ e);
    }
}
```

}

This program runs sometimes and sometimes does not run by throwing that exception

Comment: please share the code block for this

Comment: @Abhishek Anand include program and exception
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from tbl_user_history where app_key=? and rec_id= ? and caller_id=? and call_time > ? and call_time < ?;]; Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed  
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:106)

Comment: Isn't this more of a db admin question, checking if the table is properly indexed for this query or if there is some time-out setting that can be changed or even check if the query itself can be improved.

Comment: Database config using dbcp2.BasicDataSource <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
<property name="initialSize" value="15"/>
<property name="maxTotal" value="50"/>
<property name="maxIdle" value="0"/>
<property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
<property name="maxWaitMillis" value="-1"/>
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT NOW();"/>
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="10000"/>  
<property name="removeAbandonedOnMaintenance" value="true"/>
<property name="maxConnLifetimeMillis" value="-1"/>
<property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1000"/>

Comment: @joakimDanielson I have indexes for app_key, rec_id and  call_time and not for caller_id in where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching records from a huge table, It was taking more time to fetch records.
So my architect decided to have an index for the columns that we are trying to use in where clause
We used this index to solve this problem

```
CREATE INDEX call_during_time ON tbl_user_history (app_key, rec_id, caller_id, call_time);
```

Started getting faster on that index.
That solved the problem